# No figure reference number using a font size in the caption + subfigure

Tags: subfloats

A strange behaviour: if I use the package subfigure and I add the caption in a font-changing environment, I have no figure number when I call the figure by reference.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}

\section{Test}
Bla bla bla, please refer to Figure \ref{fig:flowchart}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{imgs/global_imgs/ffsmFlowChart3.pdf}
    \begin{footnotesize} \caption{FFSM++ Flowchart} \end{footnotesize}
    \label{fig:flowchart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Results in:
[image: screenshot]

If I remove subfig or I don't add the footnotesize, it works. Should I report it as a bug? Where?

Comment: Maybe you should use the `\renewcommand` in the preamble for change the captions set-up and get the typographic view you want. Therefore  you can use the `\caption` as always without edit it manually each time and avoid your document clashes to compile.

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolet for many years, `subfig`doesn't work well with `hyperref`. Package `subcaption` is a good alternative. Font swtches are, well ... switches, but not environments. Please take a mental note. Having said that, you can set the size of the caption body globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `caption` that's automatically loaded by `subfig` (unless you pass it the `caption=false` option) makes further checks to the placement of `\label` for a caption, in order to warn users making the common error of having the label *before* the caption.

You have it after, but there's a catch: the `\caption` command is inside an environment, so the label it sets gets forgotten at `\end{footnotesize}`. You indeed get the warning

```
Package caption Warning: \label without proper \caption on input line 20.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

If you remove `subfig`, you get no warning, but reference is wrong, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}

\section{A}

b

\section{Test}
Bla bla bla, please refer to Figure \ref{fig:flowchart}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{imgs/global_imgs/ffsmFlowChart3.pdf}
    \begin{footnotesize} \caption{FFSM++ Flowchart} \end{footnotesize}
    \label{fig:flowchart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

When `\label` is scanned, the most recent `\current@label` is the one issued by `\section{Test}`, because the one in the (inexistent) `footnotesize` environment is forgotten.

Use explicitly `caption` (it's better) and issue

```
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
```

One should avoid explicit markup like `\footnotesize` in the document as much as possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}

\section{A}

b

\section{Test}
Bla bla bla, please refer to Figure \ref{fig:flowchart}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{imgs/global_imgs/ffsmFlowChart3.pdf}
    \caption{FFSM++ Flowchart}
    \label{fig:flowchart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`subfigure` is obsolet for many years, `subfig` doesn't work well with
`hyperref`. Package `subcaption` is a good alternative. Font swtches
are, well ... switches, but not environments. Please take a
mental note.

Best practice is to define global things in the preamble, loading
package `subcaption` also provides the capabilities of package
`caption`. You now have access to a powerful interface.

If it should be necessary for any reason to rezise a single
caption, do it first inside the caption argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{textfont=Large,
labelfont=footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}

\section{Test}
Bla bla bla, please refer to Figure \ref{fig:flowchart}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \caption{FFSM++}
    \label{fig:flowchart}
    \caption{\scriptsize FFSM++}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]